# How do I build by own authentication/membership provider for DNN 6?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I have been looking for a better way to authenticate my users for my company's extranet. Currently we are using DNN 6.5 and I found [some information](http://www.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2009/07/13/dotnetnuke-tips-and-tricks-12-creating-your-own-authentication-provider.aspx)
 on creating my own authentication provider but it looks like its outdated. I have looked around since last friday for some uptodate information on this but so far have come up empty handed. Does anyone know where I can find a 6.0 C# version of this information.

Comment: Unfortunately that post, or one from Henry at Engage Software is likely all you'll find. The best resource would be to open up the source for one of the providers and start modifying that

Answer (score 0):

Its not outdated, it still applies.

The basics are still the same:

1. Make a copy of the existing authentication folder
2. Make your changes
3. Then, install it to the authentication system in the Admin tool